# login timeout expired error on first sql query

Tags: sql-server, authentication, timeout

I'm running SQL Server 2005 and using IIS for ASP scripts.

I have a problem with sql that is when I run a sql query (exp : http://[host name] with `localhost` as [host name]) at first time (like when I start my windows) or when the session times out due to being idle for too long, this error happens :

> Login Timeout Expired

but after that when I refresh the page, everything will be OK and it works like it should be.

Comment: Is this classic ASP or ASP.Net

Comment: its done by ASP classic.

Comment: Have you tried optimizing your query and/or increasing the SQL command timeout?

Answer (score 0):

```
It looks like it takes a long time to run the sproc the "first" time, from then on it only takes less than a sec to execute the sproc.
```

SQL Server will generate a execution plan for the stored procedure when it runs the first time, so it will cause a long duration. Then next times SQL can reuse the exection plan so the duration becomes shorter. However a duration of 46secs is abnormal, you can try to create a clustered index on the table, in order to speed up query.